# Flextable upload to confluence, xml encoding error

Tags: r, flextable

When i try to upload an rmarkdown document containing flextable to confluence (using conflr), i get the following error

```
Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  :
  Opening and ending tag mismatch: table line 47 and p [76]
```

However, if i set `ft.shadow =FALSE` as a chunk option the error does not occur and uploaded correctly.

I'm happy to work without shadow dom, but the cell coloring has disappeared so maybe the shadow dom preserves the cell colors?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked on github: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/364

conflr is outputing markdown.

This is not possible to force an HTML rendering into a markdown output. This applies to flextable and all other CSS designed HTML output.